# Can somebody explain what is happening in react-native-calendar Agenda section?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

why that exact loop condition? Also how do I load my date that comes with the data in the "strTime"?

```
  loadItems(day) {
setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = -15; i < 85; i++) {
    const time = day.timestamp + i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    const strTime = this.timeToString(time);
    if (!this.state.items[strTime]) {
      this.state.items[strTime] = [];
      const numItems = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
      for (let j = 0; j < numItems; j++) {
        this.state.items[strTime].push({
          name: 'Item for ' + strTime + ' #' + j,
          height: Math.max(50, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150))
        });
      }
    }
  }
  const newItems = {};
  Object.keys(this.state.items).forEach(key => {
    newItems[key] = this.state.items[key];
  });
  this.setState({
    items: newItems
  });
}, 1000);
```

}

Comment: This is not doing anything, this.state.items[strTime] = [];

To change state you need to call setState.

And also this one

this.state.items[strTime].push({
          name: 'Item for ' + strTime + ' #' + j,
          height: Math.max(50, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150))
        });